# Stop floating div before a specific div (universal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a div float and then stop before a specific div (in this case; the footer), it works on my screen, but when trying in a larger screen, the floating div is a little higher.

I want to avoid media screen for every specific screens as well.

```js
  $window.scroll(function() {
 
  ws_cart = $(this).scrollTop();
 
  var cart_position = $('.product_desc').position();
  var footer_position = $('.footer_position').position();
  // alert('width__>'+scWidth+' height __> '+ scHeight);
  // alert(ws_cart+'<__>'+footer_position.top);
  // alert(footer_position.top-350);
  // alert(ws_cart);
  if (scWidth >= 1024 && scWidth <= 1125) {
 
   if (ws_cart > (cart_position.top + 65)) {
    $('.product_fixed').css({
     "position" : "fixed",
     "right" : "1.6em",
     "top" : "0px",
     "z-index" : "999",
     "background" : "#fff"
    });
 
   } else {
    $('.product_fixed').css({
     "position" : "relative",
     "top" : "",
     "right" : "0",
     "width" : "320px"
    });
 
   }
 
   if (ws_cart > (cart_position.top + 65)
     && ws_cart > (footer_position.top - 624)) {
 
    $('.product_fixed').css({
     "position" : "relative",
     "right" : "0",
     "top" : "146em",
     "height" : "600px",
     "z-index" : "999",
     "background" : "#fff"
    });
   }
  } else if (scWidth >= 1125 && scWidth <= 1199) {
 
   if (ws_cart > (cart_position.top + 65)) {
    $('.product_fixed').css({
     "position" : "fixed",
     "right" : "1.6em",
     "top" : "0px",
     "z-index" : "999",
     "background" : "#fff"
    });
 
   } else {
    $('.product_fixed').css({
     "position" : "relative",
     "top" : "",
     "right" : "0",
     "width" : "320px"
    });
 
   }
 
   if (ws_cart > (cart_position.top + 65)
     && ws_cart > (footer_position.top - 460)) {
 
    $('.product_fixed').css({
     "position" : "relative",
     "right" : "0",
     "top" : "90em",
     "height" : "600px",
     "z-index" : "999",
     "background" : "#fff"
    });
   }
 
  } else if (scWidth >= 1200 && scWidth <= 2560) {
 
   if (ws_cart > (cart_position.top + 65)) {
    $('.product_fixed').css({
     "position" : "fixed",
     "right" : "1.6em",
     "top" : "0px",
     "z-index" : "999",
     "background" : "#fff"
    });
 
   } else {
    $('.product_fixed').css({
     "position" : "relative",
     "top" : "",
     "right" : "0",
     "width" : "320px"
    });
 
   }
 
   if (ws_cart > (cart_position.top + 65)
     && ws_cart > (footer_position.top - 512)) {
 
    $('.product_fixed').css({
     "position" : "relative",
     "right" : "0",
     "top" : "102em",
     "height" : "520px",
     "z-index" : "999",
     "background" : "#fff"
    });
   }
 
  }
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should really look into using style sheets and just adding/removing classes. That much inline styling is generally bad news.

Comment: Please stop where you are! First: you never want to have any concrete CSS attributes in your JS! Second: you are doing media queries in JS. Do them in CSS. Three, look up relative and fluid positioning as well as flexbox and media queries for CSS.